# pandas groupby function cannot be used

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use groupby function in pandas. However it doesn't work. Other function in pandas works very well. I'm very confused.

```
corr=corr.groupby(level='date')
print(corr)
Out[21]: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000025FC4726808> ``
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an aggregation to it, for example

```
corr.groupby(level='date').sum()
```